# SSRS Numbers appear differently than same view in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, reporting-services

In SSRS, I have a report running that pulls from a SQL view, but is for some reason showing up with insanely wrong numbers for a particular campaign.

For example, this is what I am getting in SSRS:

[SSRS Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XS8v.png)

SSRS Designer: i.stack.imgur.com/LoHaf.png

(Cant post more than 2 links

As opposed to the exact same view being shown in Excel:

[Excel Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DZif.png)

It almost seems like any lead that does not have locks or closes is being aggregated into that one campaign for some reason. I am joining 2 views together becuase there is data from 2 different systems. It works flawlessly within Excel, but I am completely stumped as to why I cannot get it working in SSRS.

I really appreciate the help.

Thanks

SQL View code

```
Select *
from xxViableLeadsVelocifyEncompassGrpCampaign
left outer join xxLocksAndCloses on xxLocksAndCloses.Campaign =       xxViableLeadsVelocifyEncompassGrpCampaign.Title
```

xxViableLeadsVelocifyEncompassGrpCampaign

```
SELECT C.[CampaignId], C.[Title], C.[Lead_Ct], cast(C.[COST] as INT) as "COST", cast(C.[COST per Lead] as int) as "Cost Per Lead", 
COUNT(V.LeadId) "Viable Leads", cast(Cast(C.[COST] as int)/COUNT(V.LeadId) as DECIMAL(10,2)) as "Cost per Viable Lead", CAST( CAST(COUNT(V.LeadId) AS FLOAT)/C.[Lead_Ct] as DECIMAL(10,2)) AS "Viable Lead Conversion"
FROM xxViableLeadsVelocifyEncompass V
INNER JOIN xxLeadCampaignGrpCountCosts C on V.CampaignId = C.CampaignId
GROUP BY C.[CampaignId], C.[Title], C.[Lead_Ct], C.[COST], C.[COST per Lead]
```

xxLeadCampaignGrpCountCosts:

```
 SELECT C.CampaignId, C.Title, 
  Count(LeadId) as Lead_Ct,
  CAST(SUM(LW.f660) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS COST,
  CAST(AVG(LW.f660) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS "COST per Lead      
  FROM [VelocifyDB].[dbo].[LeadWarehouse] LW
  INNER JOIN Campaign C ON LW.CampaignId = C.CampaignId
  WHERE DATEADD(hh, 3, LW.CreateDate) >= '7-5-2016'
  AND lw.CampaignId != '225'
  And Lw.CampaignId IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY C.CampaignId, C.Title
```

xxLocksAndCloses

```
SELECT C.Title as Campaign, 
COUNT(LeadId) as Locked_Loans,
SUM(Case when CX_CLOSING_COMPLETION IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as Closed_Loans
FROM velocifydb.dbo.Lead L 
INNER JOIN [ENCOMPASS_DW].[dbo].[Encompass_loanData] E ON L.LeadId=  E.cx_leads360id
INNER JOIN velocifydb.dbo.Campaign C ON L.CampaignId = C.CampaignId
WHERE LOCKDATE is not null AND DATEADD(hh, 3, L.CreateDate) >= '7-5-2016'
GROUP BY C.Title
```

Comment: Can you show the views and groupings in SSRS?

Comment: Edits have been made. Thank you

Comment: Your first record in the SSRS image has a positive match with your excel version. All the others are off by a lot. I bet you have a filter or a row group messed up.

Comment: Are you sure the join conditions are right? Should the tables be joining on CampaignId?